# How do I import .pyx in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have been working with a project that have .pyx files and When I run it on Ninja Ide it's doesn't recognise them! How can I solve this?
I have installed cython but nothing!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-the-easy-way) before you can import `.pyx` files:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

Comment: I try doing that but nothing's happen! Do I have to have the files in the same folder as the others normal py extension?

Comment: It needs to be somewhere on the module search path (`sys.path`). If you import a `.pyx` module and 'nothing happens', then everything shouod be ok, otherwise you'd get an error.